# Excel VBA: Transferring data from variable sheet name, run-time error '91'

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is to transfer data from the variable named sheet to a certain sheet ("SUMMARY"). Then, I want to consider a cell in the variable sheet. So if the cell > 0, then it will copy the line to SUMMARY. But I'm having an 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error. What am I doing wrong?

```
        Sub transfer()

        Dim ws As String
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim i As Long

        Dim c As Range

        n = Sheets("Start").Range("c24").Value + 3

        If n > 0 Then
            For i = 3 To n

                Dim desrow As Integer
                desrow = i - 1
                Dim rng As Range

                rng = Range("AA11:AA40")

                    For Each c In rng
                        If c = 12 Then

                             Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(desrow, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Range("C3")

                        End If
                    Next c
            Next i

        End If

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You must `Set` objects, so you need to say:

```
Set rng = Range("AA11:AA40")
```

Comment: I'm encountering a _Compile Error: Method or data member not found._ with that code.

Comment: Is the error occurring on that line, or on another line?  (If another line, which one?)  And, if on that line, is your active sheet a `Worksheet` or a `Chart`?

Comment: @LiezlMaigue - Also, if it is that line, I have sometimes seen copy/paste from posts include some invisible invalid characters, so just try deleting the line and typing it in again manually.

Comment: @LiezlMaigue - OK - try deleting and typing - it's very strange to get a "Compile error", because that line is (at least visibly) completely fine.  And I copied your code into VBA, changed the line (even using copy/paste), and then tried running it and it successfully compiled.

Comment: A minor point, but perhaps Dim rng As Range                 Set rng = Range("AA11:AA40")  shouldn't be inside the loop.

Comment: @RADO It shouldn't matter where the `Dim` is - VBA does them all as part of the compilation anyway (so you can actually put all your `Dim` statements as the last lines in your `Sub` if you like).  Only `ReDim` is an executable statement.

Comment: @YowE3K: 100% agree, I was referring more to the "set" statement - don't see a point of setting it to a fixed range multiple times. Just bad coding style IMHO.

Comment: @RADO - it's even worse coding style to not qualify which worksheet the `Range` refers to :D   I couldn't work out from the code which sheet it was meant to be referring to, or likely meant to be referring to, which is why I didn't add a qualification to it when I wrote the answer.  (I'm still scratching my head trying to work out how the code relates to the question.)  So **maybe** it is meant to be `Sheets(i).Range("AA11:AA40")`???

Comment: @YowE3K: Ha-ha, I think you are spot on!